# How can I read the value of my ASP.NET Custom RoleProvider cacheRolesInCookie config value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a custom RoleProvider that I'm using, and I've found that cacheRolesInCookie isn't working. After reading, this is expected behavior. However, I would like to override this and handle the cacheing on my own.  My problem is that I can't figure out how to read the value from the configuration file to determine if the cacheing should occur or not.  Here is my config settings...

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" 
         type="MyCompany.WebSecurity.MyRoleProvider" 
         connectionStringName="Security" 
         applicationName="TestSite" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I read the provider settings using this code:

```
var membershipSection = (MembershipSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership");
var defaultProvider = membershipSection.DefaultProvider;
var providerSettings = membershipSection.Providers[defaultProvider];

var connStringName = providerSettings.Parameters["connectionStringName"];
```

How can I get the value of the attribute cacheRolesInCookie?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. I was casting my config section to the wrong type.  HEre is what I have done now.

```
var roleManagerSection = (RoleManagerSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/roleManager");

var cacheRolesInCookie = roleManagerSection.CacheRolesInCookie;
```